# TSQL to compare data and return results on different rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will compare the same data in two tables, one is the original data and another will be an updated version of this data.  I want to compare the two datasets for any changes and return those changes.  That I have managed to do, but I'd like to return the results in different rows not in the same row.
So currently my result set looks like this:

| Type of Change | Original Staff Number | New Staff Number | Original Name | New Name | Original Title | New Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UPDATE | 1234 | 1234 | Joe Smyth | Joe Smith | Mr | Mr |
| UPDATE | 4321 | 4321 | Sally Green | Sally Green | Ms | Mrs |

I can see that it returns two Staff members who have changes in their details.  Joe Smyth's name was wrong and has been corrected to Joe Smith and Sally Green has changed from Ms to Mrs.
However, I'd like my returned dataset to be in this shape:

| Type of Change | Data Source | Staff Number | Name | Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UPDATE | Original Data | 1234 | Joe Smyth | Mr |
| UPDATE | New Data | 1234 | Joe Smith | Mr |
| UPDATE | Original Data | 4321 | Sally Green | Ms |
| UPDATE | New Data | 4321 | Sally Green | Mrs |

This is the query I used to put it this way:

First I returned any changes to a temp table.

```
    SELECT      b.StaffNumber
    INTO        #StaffNumbers
    FROM        OriginalData a
    LEFT JOIN   NewData b
    ON          a.StaffNumber = b.StaffNumber
    AND         (a.Name != b.Name
    OR          a.Title != b.Title)
    WHERE       b.StaffNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Then pulled the data I wanted from the different data sets using UNION to join them:

```
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
                SELECT      'UPDATE' as [Type Of Change],
                            'Original Data' as [Data Source],
                            StaffNumber as [Staff Number],
                            Name,
                            Title
                FROM        App_Person a
                INNER JOIN  #GmcNumber b
                ON          a.StaffNumber = b.StaffNumber
                UNION
                SELECT      'UPDATE' as [Type Of Change],
                            'New Data' as [Data Source],
                            a.StaffNumber as [Staff Number],
                            Name,
                            Title,
                FROM        PersonExtract a
                INNER JOIN  #StaffNumbers b
                ON          a.StaffNumber = b.StaffNumber
            ) sub1
    ORDER BY [Staff Number]
```

So while I'm getting the result I want, I'm wondering if there's a smarter way to do this than what I've done above.  If anybody has any ideas/suggestions.

Many thanks!!

Comment: similar questions on comparing data in 2 tables asked many times on SO

Comment: What if there is more than 1 updates for a staff ?

Comment: Do you also want rows appearing in the old set and not appearing in the updated set?

Comment: @MitchWheat my question wasn't about comparing data in 2 tables, it was if there is a better SQL solution to having the results displayed over 2 rows, other than what I provided above.

Comment: @Squirrel there is only one row for each staff member.  That one row might contain a number of changes e.g. Name change, title change.  But I'm more wondering if there is a more sophisticated SQL solution to display the results over two rows than the way I'm currently doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to unpivot the old and new data out of the join.

No temp tables necessary.

```sql
SELECT
  'UPDATE' AS [Type of Change],
  a.StaffNumber,
  v.[Data Source],
  v.Name,
  v.Title
FROM OriginalData a
JOIN NewData b ON a.StaffNumber = b.StaffNumber
    AND (a.Name != b.Name OR a.Title != b.Title)
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT 'Original Data' as [Data Source], a.Name, a.Title
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'New Data', b.Name, b.Title
) v
```

If you want all the differences, you need a `FULL JOIN`

```sql
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN a.StaffNumber IS NOT NULL AND b.StaffNumber IS NOT NULL
      THEN 'UPDATE'
    WHEN a.StaffNumber IS NULL
      THEN 'INSERT'
    ELSE 'DELETE'
    END AS [Type of Change],
  ISNULL(a.StaffNumber, b.StaffNumber) AS StaffNumber,
  v.[Data Source],
  v.Name,
  v.Title
FROM OriginalData a
FULL JOIN NewData b ON a.StaffNumber = b.StaffNumber
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.Name, a.Title INTERSECT SELECT b.Name, b.Title)
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT 'Original Data' as [Data Source], a.Name, a.Title
  WHERE a.StaffNumber IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'New Data', b.Name, b.Title
  WHERE b.StaffNumber IS NOT NULL
) v
```